# How to enumerate a zip array in swift 4 to get index for each object

Tags: arrays, zip, swift4

I need to enumerate a zipped array to check index for each object from array. Below is my code please help me out.

```
for((index1, index2),(value1, value2)) in zip(array1, array2).enumerated() {
        // INDEX OF OBJECT
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `enumerated` to know `index` of value like this way.

```
func zipArray() {
    let words = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
    let numbers = 1...4

    let zipArray = Array(zip(words, numbers))
    print(zipArray)

    for (index, tuple) in zipArray.enumerated() {
        print("Index : \(index): Word :\(tuple.0) Number : \(tuple.1)")
    }
}
```

Once `zip` perform on two array then it returns another array with pair of inputs.

So you can perform `enumerated` operation on zipped array using above code and get `index` and `value` as tuple. Then for individual element of tuple index would be same.

There may be better way. But this will fulfill your purpose of index.

Answer (score 5):

Once you zip the array it is having only one index. Just use it as normal enumerations.

```
let arr1 = ["1","2","3"]
let arr2 = ["A","B"]
let arr3 = zip(arr1, arr2)
print(arr3)

for (index, (x,y)) in arr3.enumerated() {

    print(index, y)

}
```

enjoy!